# Sharepoint 2013 post from hosted app returns -1

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-rest-api, cross-domain

I created an Sharepoint-hosted application with angularjs.

And ran into a problem, my post request returns status -1, but saves the data. How to fix it?

My Lists posted on SPHostUrl.

Here is my base post service

```
     var postRequest = function (data, url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: baseUrl + url,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function (result) {
            deferred.reject(result.status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

And here is post service

```
    var addNew = function (certificate) {
        var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.CertificatesListItem' },
            FullName: certificate.FullName,
            TypeOfCertificateId: certificate.TypeOfCertificateId,
            Validity: certificate.Validity
        };
        var url = '/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists' + "/GetByTitle('Certificates')/Items?@target='" + window._spApplicationInfo.SPHostUrl + "'";
        return baseService.postRequest(data, url);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault.

I used simple div's and button without any type.

My solution is to add $event.preventDefault():

template.html

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="addTypeOfCertificate(typeOfCertificate, $event)">Сохранить</button>
```

and addTypeOfCertificate function:

```
        $scope.addTypeOfCertificate = function (typeOfCertificate, $event) {

           $event.preventDefault();
           save();
        }
```